# Meteor Pagination with alethes:pages

Tags: meteor, pagination

I'm using alethes:pagination but I don't understand how to make it work. I have 4 posts in my collection and I want to display 2 per page. Here's the code.

app.js

```
BlogPosts = new Mongo.Collection("blogPosts");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.body.helpers({
        blogPosts: function() {
            return BlogPosts.find({});
        }
    });
}

Pages = new Meteor.Pagination(BlogPosts, {
    itemTemplate: "post",
    perPage: 2
});
```

app.html

```
<head>
  <title>pagination</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> pages}}
    {{> pagesNav}}
</body>

<template name="post">
    {{title}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide 2 templates name to the alethes backed collection.

One for the page itself, and another for the items of your paginated content.

In your JS

```
PaginatedStuff = new Meteor.Pagination(Polls, {
  perPage:6,
  templateName: 'paginatedStuff',
  itemTemplate: 'stuffListItem'
});
```

Where you want to have your paginated content :

```
{{>paginatedStuff}}
```

And finally the two templates

```
<template name="paginatedStuff">
    {{> pages}} 
    {{> pagesNav}}<!-- bottom navigation -->
</template>

<template name="stuffListItem">
    <!-- stuff to display your item here -->
</template>
```